# Firefox: combine bookmarks toolbar and tabbar

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

I am looking for a way to 'minify' the Firefox UI by combining the bookmarks toolbar with the tabbar.

- The easiest way I could see this done, is by simply moving the Bookmarks left of the tabs on the tabbar. I do not have the knowledge of writing my own userChrome.css styles, but it seems possible to do it this way.
- Another more difficult way to do this, would be by making it work similar to Windows 7's taskbar. What I mean by this, is to have a bookmark toolbar, and clicking on a bookmark would turn it into a tab, just like clicking an icon in the taskbar in Windows 7 would turn that into a 'program'.

Ultimately, it comes down to this: by default, you have two toolbars: a bookmarks toolbar and a tabbar. I would like to combine these into one toolbar.

Comment: I've probably not understood this correctly, but the Bookmarks Toolbar contains _bookmarks_ and the _Tab bar_ consists of your open pages? They are not really merge-able as they contain different things? You can _open_ all the bookmarks on your Bookmarks Toolbar by right mouse on the Bookmarks Toolbar and selecting "Open All in Tabs" from the context menu. This could be perceived as 'merging the Bookmarks Toolbar with the Tab bar'?!

Comment: I'll rewrite the question.

Comment: This isn't too much of an answer but a way to gain back that space while not making the bookmarks toolbar too inaccessible is to install the [Bookmarks Toolbar Button](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/55716) which makes the Bookmark button in the customize view open the toolbar instead of the sidebar, or maybe the [Bookmarks Menu](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/12016/), which turns the toolbar into a menu (or is it the Menubar menu? I don't remember).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have always been able to move around all items in the toolbars by View > Toolbars > Customize.

Also, with Firefox 4 you can move tabs in the titlebar and also move bookmarks up there, or you can put your location bar next to tabs. What you like.

I realize this question is old but I found it when searching for pretty much the same.
I really want the pin functionality of Windows 7 Superbar with Firefox tabs. Well I guess app tabs are pretty much it since you can set them to not load when Firefox starts, they will just sit there until you open them. That could remove the need for bookmarks toolbar.

Comment: Tried it in Firefox 4, and I could indeed just move them onto the tabbar like I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes close to what you are suggesting is App-Tabs
(which are in the firefox 4 beta)

So you "pin" these tabs( in this case your bookmarks- say email, superuser.com) to the left hand side of your tabbar.

you can't accidentall close them, and they will reopen when you reopen firefox. - rather like the windows 7 taskbar buttons.

**Edit:** There are addons with this ability as well,

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/47734/ - hasn't been reviewed by Mozilla though, so use with care. and I think one of those Tab addons - Tabkit? (can't remember) also has a similar function.

Comment: I have rewritten my post in the hope of making it more clear.

I have tried App Tabs but they are not exactly convenient for me.

Comment: Accepted your answer, guess this is the closest I can get without writing an addon myself.